# String replace doesn't work when group identifier is near a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script like this:

```
$year = 2020
$string = 'Const conToYear As String = "2018"'
$newString = $string -replace '(Const conToYear As String = ")(\d{4})(")', "`$1$year`$3"
Write-Host $newString
```

It gives output `$12020"` but I need `Const conToYear As String = "2020"`. I use in few places similar replace pattern, using groups and variables and they work.

What is funny, when I do:

```
$year = 2020
$string = 'Const conToYear As String = "2018"'
$newString = $string -replace '(Const conToYear As String = ")(\d{4})(")', "`$1`$1$year"
Write-Host $newString
```

Then I get `Const conToYear As String = "$12020`, so it looks like the second occurrence of `$1` which is near variable is not interpreted as I expected.

How to solve this? I tried google it, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualify your group numbers with `{}`:

```
$year = 2020
$string = 'Const conToYear As String = "2018"'
$newString = $string -replace '(Const conToYear As String = ")(\d{4})(")', "`${1}$year`${3}"
Write-Host $newString
```

Comment: Could you add something why `\`$1` in this case doesn't work? Does it mean it's safer to use `\`${1}` than `\`$1`?

Comment: @Hostel, it doesn't work because when `$year` is expanded, it will try to process regex group 12020 instead of just group 1. The regex engine sees `$12020`.

Comment: Exactly what @AdminOfThings says - the regex parser sees the sequence `$12020` and goes "that's not for me, I only support 0 through 9"

Answer (score 2):

Here's the powershell 6 and above version.  Referring to the capture groups takes a little doing.  But you don't have to mix variables and the replace operator special $ codes.

```
$year = 2020
$string = 'Const conToYear As String = "2018"'
$string -replace '(Const conToYear As String = ")(\d{4})(")',
  { $_.groups[1].value + $year + $_.groups[3].value }

Const conToYear As String = "2020"
```